# 組版文字について:QTextEdit関連

Tags: python, qt

QTextEditで文書の作成プログラムを作っています。
ルビの入れ方や罫線など、Wordソフトで拡張書式
と言われている部分の実装ができません。
日本語組版というものです。
HTMLでルビを入れようにも、対応していない
ブラウザで（）書きにされてしまいます。
よってHTMLやCSSも対応ブラウザでないという
事で一蹴されてしまいます。
　自分のプログラムにこういうものを組み
込むための方向性というか、手がかりが全く
つかめません。組版の本やウェブページは
ありますが、組版そのものの解説ばかり
です。JIS X 4051　が、日本語組版の
規格みたいなのですが、私はその導入自体
をどうすればいいのか
悩んでいます。
　何かご存知の方はご教授ください。

Comment: `QTextEdit`と書かれていますが、PyQtを利用しての実現を考えていらっしゃいますか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。一番理想的なのがPyQt、PySideでの実装です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextEdit`で表現できるものはQtのドキュメント「[Supported HTML Subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)」に記載がある範囲です。(HTML4のサブセットとのことです) これを読むとルビ表現はできないようです。

ですので、`QTextDocument`を用いて自力で文書構造を実現する方法になるかと思います。

なお、Word文書を例に書かれていたので、ODF(OpenDocument Format)データが読み込めないかと思いましたが、本家に同じ質問([Read .odf file with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606782/read-odf-file-with-qt)(2012-05-07))があり、Qtだけでは難しい旨
回答がついていました。

Comment: QTextDocumentを駆使すればできない話ではないという理解をしてもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: [`QTextDocument`を利用した文書表示のサンプル](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-richtext-textobject-example.html)等を読んでの判断ですが、できない話ではないと思います。

Comment: おかげさまで、有力な情報を得ました。QTextObject,QTextObjectInterfaceとあたりをつけていただいたおかげです。[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232882/nice-text-formatting-in-qtextedit-like-qt-creator-does]です。まだほかにも情報があるかもしれませんし、自分のコードはうまく動かないのでもう少し頑張ります。

Comment: 一応実装を行う事が出来ました。完全ではないとは言え、ここまで前進できたので、いったん閉めようと思います。まだいろいろな問題があると思いますが、その時は別の質問を出そうと思っています。